# symfony 2 form type collection, change label for each new property from model

Tags: forms, symfony

I have 4 entities as `Product`, `ProductFeatures`, `Goods`, `GoodsFeaturesValue` and relations between them.
I add some `Features` for `Product` and then I whant create form with static fields Goods + some new `Features` from `Product` for this `Goods`. 
Values for each `Goods` saved in `GoodsFeaturesValue`.

How to build this form in "symfony way"?

UPDATED

I use collection for other `Features` and this work fine, but how i can set label from `ProductFeatures` relation for each Value? I can do this when render templemate, but this is bad :)?

```
//GoodsFormType class
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
            ->add('name')
            //other property...
            ->add('values', 'collection', array(
                'required' => true,
                'type' => new GoodsFeaturesValueFormType(),
                'allow_add' => false,
                'allow_delete' => false,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ))
    ;
}

//GoodsFeaturesValueFormType
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
            ->add('value', 'text')
    ;
}
  //controller
  public function saveAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $product = $em->getRepository('ShopCoreBundle:Product')->find($id);

    if (!$product)
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(sprintf('Product with id %s not found', $id));

    $features = $em->getRepository('ShopCoreBundle:ProductFeatures')->findByProduct($id);
    $goods = new Goods();
    $goods->setProduct($product);

    foreach ($features as $feature) {
        $entity = new GoodsFeaturesValue();
        $entity->setFeatures($feature);
        $entity->setGoods($goods);
        $entity->setProduct($product);
        $goods->addGoodsFeaturesValue($entity);
    }

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $form = $this->createForm(new GoodsFormType(), $goods);
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($goods);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('core_product_index'));
    }



    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'goods' => $goods,
        'product' => $product,
        'features' => $features,
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what i wanted for Dynamic Attribute.
You can use `FormEvent` and `EventSubscriber` to do this as Dynamic Generate Form.
http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html

So, at `GoodsFeaturesValueFormType` class, you create new `EventSubscriber` and with `preSetData`, set the label with data.

**UPDATE**: Symfony default `ResizeFormListener` does not pass the value to it, cause so, it will be an error. To support this, modify `ResizeFormListener` (which collection use) as below

```
[before]
    91         // Then add all rows again in the correct order                                                            
    92         foreach ($data as $name => $value) {                                                                       
    93             $form->add($this->factory->createNamed($this->type, $name, null, array_replace(array(                  
    94                 'property_path' => '['.$name.']',                                                                  
    95             ), $this->options)));
    96         }
```

---

```
[modified]
    91         // Then add all rows again in the correct order                                                            
    92         foreach ($data as $name => $value) {                                                                       
    93             $form->add($this->factory->createNamed($this->type, $name, $value, array_replace(array(                  
    94                 'property_path' => '['.$name.']',                                                                  
    95             ), $this->options)));
    96         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **[collection Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)**, simple example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#adding-and-removing-items

Comment: I use it for add Features for Product, but how use it for create new Goods?
Collection Type uses for one to many relations.